# ZenDesk iOS SDK : How to generate JWT endpoint URL?

Tags: ios, zendesk

I am working on iOS app where i need to integrate ZenDesk SDK. I have setup AppId, zendeskurl, clientId.

```
 [[ZDKConfig instance] initializeWithAppId:@"xxxxxxx"
                               zendeskUrl:@"https://xxxxx"
                              andClientId:@"xxxxxx"];

 [ZDCChat configure:^(ZDCConfig *defaults) {

    defaults.accountKey = @"xxxxx";
    defaults.preChatDataRequirements.department = xxxx;
    defaults.preChatDataRequirements.message = xxxx;
}];
```

When i set authentication method as Anonymous, its working fine.

```
  [ZDKConfig instance].userIdentity = [[ZDKJwtIdentity alloc]
                                         initWithJwtUserIdentifier:@"xxx@gmail.com"];
```

But when i set JWT as an authentication method. It's not working.

[image]

Comment: anyluck solving this issue mate?

Answer (score 1):

Kirti, I know this is a little old but I just went through this setup and finally got it working so hopefully it might help others.

Setting the JWT endpoint as your authentication method requires you to have your own server endpoint that Zendesk can then go to to let you verify an identity.

So in the field that says JWT URL, you shouldn't have the url to your ZenDesk instance. You should have https://yourserver.com/verifyJWT (that's just an example endpoint). Then at that endpoint your server should verify that the JWT is valid and return either a 200 HTTP response or a 401 HTTP response (success and unauthorized respectively) More details from ZenDesk [here](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203663816-Setting-up-single-sign-on-with-JWT-JSON-Web-Token-).

Then using the iOS SDK you need to set an identity so ZenDesk knows what to send to your server endpoint. The key is getting an identity from your server (probably as a response to a login) that you can then verify when ZenDesk hits your endpoint. The identity can be any string as long as it's in a format that you can verify.

You will also probably need to know how JWT's are formatted. I found [this](https://jwt.io/introduction/) article very helpful.